# Display Windows application via SSH X11 on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, x11-forwarding

Is possible to Run SSH server on Windows then make X11 connection forwarding enabled from Linux to this Windows and display Windows application on Linux?

Comment: Here check this X11 Forwarding using SSH - http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XDMCP-HOWTO/ssh.html

Comment: This explain situation where application is running on Linux and displayed remote on Windows/Linux. My problem is how to run application on Windows and display it remote on Linux. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Linux to Windows

An X11 application uses an X Server to display the app's Graphical User Interface (GUI). Microsoft Windows does not come with an X Server out of the box so it can't display them BUT you can install an X Server application that will allow for that and there are free ones you can download and install.

---

### Windows to Linux

Going the other way, displaying Microsoft Windows applications on Linux, it not possible because Windows uses a different GUI system and as far as I know there is no "server" system that would display a Windows application on a Linux display.

BUT there are ways around that. For Example:

- **RDP** - Fast/Native technology by MS to remotely connect to a windows desktop. It is built in to Windows but needs to be enabled/configured. There are Linux clients.
- **VNC** - Free alternative. You need to install server software on Windows side.
- **Teamviewer** - Commercial app to access Windows desktop. Free for personal use. Has linux client

HTH

Comment: I use rdesktop for RDP.  seems to be in a lot of Linux Distros.
If you're looking at commercial, there's also Citrix.

Comment: I am familiar with RDP and VNC. But I am in situation where RDP cannot be used due to configured policy which I cannot change (I am not admin on Windows). I have searched for open source reimplementation RDP server for windows but no luck. For same policy reasons TW cannot be used also. Portable VNC is one possibility but seems like overhead compared to RDP. AFAIK RDP transfers object and VNC images. Also the output quality of VNC cannot be compared to RDP. This project seems interesting but I did not try it yet https://winswitch.org/downloads/

Comment: VNC is fine when used on a LAN and can be configured for slower links. I wouldn't dismiss it.

Comment: If you can execute VNC you should have no problem launching TeamViewer. Installing either as a service needs admin privileges though. Winswitch is basically all the various remote protocols [bundled](https://winswitch.org/documentation/protocols/) together, X11, SSH, VNC, RDP, NX, so there is no difference.

Comment: AFAIK TW uses some 3rd party serves (or was it logmein ... do not know exactly). Does TW transfers objects or images? If WinSwitch supports so many protocols it is only client, something like remmmina? Also what VNC server/client are you recommending (multi platform will be fine)? There are plenty of. I had on Linux xtightvncviewer which is client. But the feature I miss is zoom resp. full screen. So I end up with java.jar tightVNC.

Comment: TeamViewer needs server to get through firewalls. It can [connect directly to LAN PCs as well](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/40-Can-TeamViewer-be-used-within-a-local-network-LAN-only.aspx). It can share clipboard and transfer files. For VNC, I can't recommend any, I don't use it.